# Poner div. o section. en el selector CSS

Tags: css, class, id, selectores

buenas!
Estoy trabajando en una web ya dada, y me encuentro en el css que algunos selectores de id o de clase, son llamados de tal manera:

```
section#nuestroid{}
div.nuestraclase{}
```

¿Qué diferencia hay entre hacer esto y ponerlo como yo hacía hasta ahora?
Así es como solía hacerlo:

```
#nuestroid{}
.nuestraclase{}
```

¿En qué casos se utiliza?

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La única diferencia sería que en el caso de "section#nuestroid{}" solo afectaría a aquél elemento con id "nuestroid" que esté dentro de en un elemento "section", y en "div.nuestraclase{}" solo afectaría a aquellos elementos que contengan la clase "nuestraclase" dentro de DIVs.

Por ejemplo, aquí aplicarían los dos formatos mencionados:

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <div id="nuestroid">1234</div>
    <div class="nuestraclase"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Pero aquí solo aplicarían las segundas, ya que no está dentro de un section ni la clase nuestraclase pertenece a un DIV:

```html
 <header>
  <div id="nuestroid">1234</div>
  <span class="nuestraclase"></div>
 </header>
```

Hacen prácticamente lo mismo, pero el primer formato es más específico, requiere que nuestroid esté dentro de un section y que la clase nuestraclase pertenezca a un DIV.

Son igual de válidas las dos formas.
Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Genial muchas gracias!!

Comment: Debo hacer una corrección en mi respuesta, en el primer código que he puesto no aplicaría la primera regla ya que el id nuestroid debe pertenecer a section y no a uno de sus componentes de forma que solo aplicaría a casos como <section id='nuestroid'>, para que aplicase a alguno de sus componentes deberíamos poner un espacio entre section y #nuestroid, de la siguiente forma "section #nuestroid {}"